# In for loop of fetch requests, how do you pass "i" value into body payload that's been defined as template literal outside the loop?

Tags: javascript, fetch, template-literals

I want to make multiple fetch requests, each request has a different payload, `studentID` in this example. Every loop changes the studentID, but the payload is defined as a template literal variable outside the loop for readability. Is there a way to get for loop iterator value to the payload (defined outside)?

```
var payload=`{"studentID": ${studentID}}` //expecting studentID to be iterated in loop
var myInit = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: payload
};

for(var studentID = 0; studentID <= 10; studentID++) {
    fetch(URI, myInit)
    .then( r => r.json() )
    .then( r => console.log(r) 
    .catch(e => console.log(e));
}
```

studentID values (0,1,2,3...) cannot get into myInit's `payload` template.

Comment: wrap that in a function which takes id as input and return myInit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a function instead.

```
const makeInit = studentID => ({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: `{"studentID": ${studentID}}`
});
for(var studentID = 0; studentID <= 10; studentID++) {
    fetch(URI, makeInit(studentID))
```

Maybe don't stringify manually.

```
const makeInit = studentID => ({
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ studentID })
});
for(var studentID = 0; studentID <= 10; studentID++) {
    fetch(URI, makeInit(studentID))
```